# Combinatorial analysis:Chain letter problem

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, self-learning

In a population of **n+1** people a man, the 'progenitor', sends out  letters to two persons, the "first generation". These repeat the performance and, generally, each member of the **rth generation** sends out letters to two persons chosen at random. I want to find the probability that generations number **1,2,...,r** will not include the progenitor. I want to find a median of the distribution, supposing **n** to be  large.

Answer: My answer is not matching with the answer provided.My answer is $(1-\frac2n)^{2^r}$. Whereas answer given is $(1-\frac2n)^{2^r-2}$.

How to find median of this distribution?

Comment: Is the first generation just the seed person or is it the first two people who receive the letters?  Let's say it is the first two people.  Then generation $1$ definitely does not include the seed so the answer should be $1$.  you get $\left(1-\frac 2n\right)^2$ which is not $1$.  The given answer is $\left(1-\frac 2n \right)^0=1$ so the given answer appears to work in this case.

Comment: Is the distribution you are trying to find the median of the distribution of the number of people who have received letters?  Assuming the first generation is the one after the progenitor, there are $2^{k}$ people who receive letters in the $k^{\text{th}}$ generation.  When the $r^{\text{th}}$ generation receives its letters the number of people who have sent out two letters each is $2+4+8+\ldots 2^{r-1}=2^r-2$.  The chance that none of these were sent to the progenitor is then $(1-\frac 2n)^{2^r-2}$